# JSlider for doubles

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jslider

I am making a GUI (using swing) for a poker framework and need some sort of slider to allow players to select a bet size. However the Swing `JSlider` only works with int values whereas I need something that can support doubles for 1 decimal point. Are there any libraries I can use, or tricks with the `JSlider`?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548606/java-link-jslider-and-jtextfield-for-float-value

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can multiply the value by 10

EDIT

You can change the labels displayed as follows:

```
Hashtable labelTable = new Hashtable();
labelTable.put( new Integer( 0 ), new JLabel("0.0") );
labelTable.put( new Integer( 5 ), new JLabel("0.5") );
labelTable.put( new Integer( 10 ), new JLabel("1.0") );
framesPerSecond.setLabelTable( labelTable );
```

Comment: You can use setLabelTable to change the components (JLabels) used for the values displayed.

Comment: I forgot about that - deleting my post in favor of that solution.

Comment: What about the situation where the minimum number must be a double, lets say 5.5, I would make the JLabel read 5.5 and map the integer 5 to this JLabel. But when I call JSlider.getValue() I will get 5, and not 5.5. Any ideas on how to deal with this?

Comment: You would make the minimum value be 55, not 5, and would then divide any value by 10.0 to get the decimal point value.

Comment: If anyone else reads this in 2022 or later, please note: constructor Integer(int) is deprecated; the static factory Integer.valueOf(int) is generally a better choice.

Answer (score 7):

One **trick** you can use with JSlider is to use the units in cents. So if you want the user to select an amount between 1 and 10 dollars you actually set the JSlider to the range 100 to 1000. Then you simply convert the value to dollars and cents when the user selects a value.

You can then use a Dictionary of values to specify what label is displayed at any value on the slider. Use the `setLabelTable()` method for this.

Comment: What about the situation where the minimum number must be a double, lets say 5.5, I would make the JLabel read 5.5 and map the integer 5 to this JLabel. But when I call JSlider.getValue() I will get 5, and not 5.5. Any ideas on how to deal with this?

Comment: The minimum value in this case is 550. You map this to 5.50 for display. When you get the value that the user selected you simply divide by 100 to get 5.5.