# How to get Matisse GUI to show up my custom added components?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, components

I'm making my really first "graphic" program in **Java** and almost all the components I used were added by dragging them into the **NetBeans GUI**, that's okay.

However, I had to add some code into a new void outside the famous: `initComponents()` because I needed a JSlider which can interpret floats binded into a JTextField and viceversa, but that's not the main topic.

```
public AlbedoSection() {//Constructor
    initComponents();//Generated by the GUI mostly
    myInitComponents();//The void that I'm talking about 
                       //which adds a custom Slider with a TextField
                       //But doesnt show up in the GUI Editor
}

public void myInitComponents() {
    final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.####");
    //final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    final JTextField text = new JTextField(20);
    final DoubleJSlider slider = new DoubleJSlider(0, 10000, 0, 100);
    slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            text.setText(df.format(slider.getScaledValue()));
        }
    });
    text.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
            String typed = text.getText();

            double value = Double.parseDouble(typed) * slider.scale;
            slider.setValue((int) value);
        }
    });
    slider.setBounds(700,450,200,30);
    text.setBounds(900,450,50,30);
    add(text); //adding textfield into the frame
    add(slider); // adding slider into the frame
}
```

I also set the components up and the program itsef works perfectly when I [compile it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8IWM.png), BUT the new "hardcoded" components doesn't seem to show up into the [GUI Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ob6qf.png) which led me to wonder If there's a way of doing that.

Forgive me If that's a stupid question, I'm just really new into programming.

EDIT1: Put two Images and Added code (the myInitComponents code is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548606/java-link-jslider-and-jtextfield-for-float-value?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa))

Comment: So you're in essence asking why code *not shown* is not working, and this is ***very*** hard for us to answer.

Comment: Please create and post your [mcve] with your question so we can see *and* run your code. Also do you understand how Swing layouts work? If not, perhaps study the tutorials for this as it may give you the answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sorry about that, I edited my post, hopefuly you can understand better what's my issue

Comment: Yeah, you're not taking layout managers into consideration. Consider this: create a JPanel in NetBeans designer, give it a BorderLayout, add it to the main GUI, and then add your JSlider **to that JPanel**.

Comment: and yes, read/study the layout manager tutorials. Google them.

Comment: I'll take note, thanks for your patience